# Why do I get "Required key not available" when install 3rd party kernel modules or after a kernel upgrade?

Tags: kernel, uefi, secure-boot, dkms

This issue happens only on UEFI systems with enabled Secure Boot.

When I try to install DKMS modules like VirtualBox, Nvidia, or Broadcom drivers, they do not install and I get `Required key not available` when I try to `modprobe` them.

VirtualBox complains that `vboxdrv` is not loaded.

Broadcom `wl` driver is shown in `lspci -k` as a kernel module but is not in use. `sudo modprobe wl` throws `Required key not available`.

Also this issue may happen when I install some kernel modules from git sources.

This issue may appear after a kernel update as disabled wireless adapter, black screen after a reboot, etc.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Similar: https://askubuntu.com/questions/760671/could-not-load-vboxdrv-after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-16-04-and-i-want-to-keep-secur

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/59536913/3291390](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59536913/3291390)

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Since Ubuntu kernel 4.4.0-20 the `EFI_SECURE_BOOT_SIG_ENFORCE` kernel config has been enabled. That prevents from loading unsigned third party modules if UEFI Secure Boot is enabled.

The easiest way to fix this issue is to **disable Secure Boot** in UEFI (BIOS) settings.

In most cases you can get into UEFI settings using grub menu. Press <kbd>ESC</kbd> button on booting, get into grub menu and select System Setup. Secure Boot option should be in "Security" or "Boot" section of the UEFI.

You can get into UEFI directly, but it depends on your hardware. Read your computer manual to see how to get there. It may be <kbd>Del</kbd>, or <kbd>F2</kbd> on boot, or something else.

An alternative way is to disable Secure Boot using `mokutil`.

Since Ubuntu kernel build 4.4.0-21.37 this can be fixed by running

```
sudo apt install mokutil
sudo mokutil --disable-validation
```

It will require to create a password. The password should be at least 8 characters long. After you reboot, UEFI will ask if you want to change security settings. Choose "Yes".

Then you will be asked to enter the previously created password. Some UEFI firmware asks not for the full password, but to enter some characters of it, like 1st, 3rd, etc. Be careful. Some people do not understand this. I did not get  it from the first attempt either ;-)

**Update:** Now this kernel config is enabled in all supported Ubuntu kernels. Ubuntu 16.04, 15.10 and 14.04 are affected.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. @Sputnik answer does. But still, I'd like to know why mokutil is asking me for a password and when do I need it?

Comment: @AlwinKesler It asks for a password which it will validate after reboot, before the changes to the MOK database are actually carried out. Without this, a rogue process could change keys in the MOK database which become effective after the next reboot. Also, now the platform 'knows' that the person requesting the change is the same person who is physically present after the reboot, and will thus have passed hardware security measures, such as having physical access to the machine and knowing the boot time system password.

Comment: @Pilot6: I am still on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS due to some technical issues. Thanks a lot for updating the answer.

Comment: mokutil did not work for me on a Toshiba laptop in 16.04. It ran just fine, but upon startup the secure boot was still there. I ended up using the first option, pressing escape upon boot and turning off secure boot.

Comment: mokutil worked great for me on a Lenovo X1 Carbon gen3 - and the part about the password characters on reboot was a really good heads-up!!

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu 18.04. Couldn't figure out for the life of me why installing nvidia drivers wasn't working via any means, or even by reverting to 16.04. Gah! This fixed it. So much time wasted.

Comment: My Ubuntu system was really laggy. Made no sense since this was a brand new laptop. Now I realize the CPU was doing everything and my video card was sitting idle the whole time. This link also helped - https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/install-nvidia-driver-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: This is not the required fix. One should not need to reboot.

Comment: I dual boot. I bet windows turned secure boot back on during updates...

Comment: dear Pilot6 could you help me on this topic https://askubuntu.com/questions/1332631/how-to-create-a-secure-boot-enabled-usb-flash

Answer (score 53):

As [suggested](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760671/could-not-load-vboxdrv-after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-16-04/768310#comment1149810_768310) by user @zwets, I'm copying (with edits) [an answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/768310/101985) here:

Since kernel version 4.4.0-20, it was enforced that **unsigned** kernel modules will not be allowed to run with Secure Boot enabled. If you'd want to keep Secure Boot **and** also run these modules, then the next logical step is to **sign** those modules.

So let's try it.

1. Create signing keys

   ```
   openssl req -new -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout MOK.priv -outform DER -out MOK.der -nodes -days 36500 -subj "/CN=Descriptive name/"
   ```
2. Sign the module

   ```
   sudo /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/scripts/sign-file sha256 ./MOK.priv ./MOK.der /path/to/module
   ```

**Note 1**: There can be multiple files to be signed for a single driver/module, so `/path/to/module` may need to be replaced with `$(modinfo -n <modulename>)`, e.g. `$(modinfo -n vboxdrv)`

**Note 2**: `sudo kmodsign sha512 ./MOK.priv ./MOK.der /path/to/module` is an alternative if `sign-file` is not available.

3. Register the keys to Secure Boot

   ```
   sudo mokutil --import MOK.der
   ```

   Supply a password for later use after reboot
4. `Reboot` and follow instructions to Enroll MOK (Machine Owner Key). Here's a [sample](https://sourceware.org/systemtap/wiki/SecureBoot) with pictures. The system will reboot one more time.

If the key has been enrolled properly, it will show up under `sudo mokutil --list-enrolled`.

Please let me know if your modules would run this way on Ubuntu 16.04 (on kernel 4.4.0-21, I believe).

**Resources:** Detailed website [article for Fedora](http://gorka.eguileor.com/vbox-vmware-in-secureboot-linux/) and [Ubuntu implementation](https://github.com/Canonical-kernel/Ubuntu-kernel/blob/master/Documentation/module-signing.txt) of module signing. (they've been working on it) ;-)

**Additional resource:** I created a bash script for my own use every time `virtualbox-dkms` upgrades and thus overwrites the signed modules. Check out my [`vboxsign` originally on GitHub](https://www.majlovesreg.one/sign-virtualbox-on-ubuntu-16-04-with-secure-boot-enabled).

Additional note for the security (extra-)conscious: ;-)

Since the private key you created (`MOK.priv` in this example) can be used by anyone who can have access to it, it is good practice to keep it secure. You may `chmod` it, encrypt (`gpg`) it, or store it somewhere else safe(r). Or, as [noted in this comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760671/could-not-load-vboxdrv-after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-16-04/768310#comment1149825_768310), remove the option `-nodes` in step number 1. This will encrypt the key with a passphrase.

Comment: On Ubuntu 14.10 I continued to see 'required key not available' trying to install a [broadcom driver](https://www.broadcom.com/support/802.11) compiled from source, despite preregistering the key and signing the driver. Disabling validation worked.

Comment: This worked for me for VirtualBox and Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: I get the following error in step 3: "EFI variables are not supported on this system". "dmesg" has no efi entries ("dmesg | grep efi" has no results) What else can I do? Thanks

Comment: You can substitute the path in with $(modinfo -n modulename)

Comment: On Ubuntu 18.04 here, insmod for talpa_syscallhook.ko module continues saying "Required key not available" despite I have signed that module, and all other modules in the same directory for the Sophos AV just in case. The key has been successfully registered as I can see it when I list all mok keys. Any ideas on how to proceed?

Comment: @FranMarzoa For step 2, note that there can be multiple files to be signed for a single driver/module (hence the `$(modinfo -n <modulename>`)

Answer (score 8):

You can disable Secure Boot (UEFI) in the BIOS with the following steps:

1. Reboot your machine and enter the BIOS Menu (In my case pressing F2)
2. Search for Secure Boot and change to Legacy

In an ASUS motherboard:

- Go to the Advanced Mode (F7)
- Go in the Secure Boot option under the Boot section
- Change "Windows UEFI mode" with "Other OS"
- Save and restart to apply settings (F10)

Comment: Secure Boot and "Legacy" are different settings.

Comment: But if you have "legacy boot" enabled instead of UEFI, does that entail that Secure Boot is not enabled?

Comment: @Supernormal, yes, this is what I understand.

Comment: IMHO the best way to deal with this - `if you need to be able to load 3rd party kmods` - is to build a stock kernel, using your distros /boot/config-* file for the initial `.config`. Alternatively, rebuild the distro kernel but remove all the patches that deal with mok and kernel lockdown.

Comment: Just to put my previous comment into context: I had reasons to build a recent kernel from Debian Buster (undoubtedly used by Ubuntu too) and discovered I couldn't load my ZFS kmods DESPITE SECURE BOOT BEING DISABLED. Must be because I did NOT use the corresponding config for my build. Or else because not everything required to build a fully functional kernel is provided. To think I'm moving to Linux because of the SIP mess in Darwin...

Answer (score 3):

You can also Disable Secure Boot in shim-signed running `sudo update-secureboot-policy`. This [wiki page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UEFI/SecureBoot/DKMS) explains this method:

> - Open a terminal (Ctrl + Alt + T), and execute sudo update-secureboot-policy and then select Yes.
> - Enter a temporary password between 8 to 16 digits. (For example, 12345678, we will use this password later
> - Enter the same password again to confirm.
> - Reboot the system and press any key when you see the blue screen (MOK management
> - Select Change Secure Boot state
> - Enter the password you had selected in Step 2 and press Enter.
> - Select Yes to disable Secure Boot in shim-signed.
> - Press Enter key to finish the whole procedure.
>
> You can still enable Secure Boot in shim-signed again. Just execute
>
> sudo update-secureboot-policy --enable
> and then follow the steps above

Answer (score 0):

If you ended up here because of VMWare Workstation on Ubuntu like I did, with:

> Could not open dev vmmon: No such file or directory.Please make sure that the kernel module `vmmon'

I found a fix [here from Edson Junior](https://gist.github.com/edsonmoreirajr/8c2757d9d0381224c60ce5c23f546ef5). When I tried to run when I tried to run `mokutil --import MOK.der` from the [official VMWare instructions](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2146460) I got an error saying:

> Required key not available

Edson's code fixed both errors for me:

```
# I noticed when I did this and when he did it two of the builds failed
$ sudo vmware-modconfig --console --install-all

$ openssl req -new -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout VMWARE15.priv -outform DER -out VMWARE15.der -nodes -days 36500 -subj "/CN=VMWARE/"

$ sudo /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/scripts/sign-file sha256 ./VMWARE15.priv ./VMWARE15.der $(modinfo -n vmmon)

$ sudo /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/scripts/sign-file sha256 ./VMWARE15.priv ./VMWARE15.der $(modinfo -n vmnet)

$ tail $(modinfo -n vmmon) | grep "Module signature appended"

$ sudo mokutil --import VMWARE15.der

now reboot

$ reboot
```

He also references a YouTube video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=be-nIv57LmA&ab_channel=BeTrend)